# Improved Betrand's postulate

Tags: prime-numbers, conjectures, prime-gaps

I want to show that $2p_{n-2} \geq p_{n}-1$...

**Bertand's postulate** shows us that $4p_{n-2}\geq p_{n}$ but can we improve on this?

any ideas?

Comment: I have to go now, but I'm wondering if we could show that $2p_{n-2} <p_{n}$ - is false for $n=3$, and then disprove the rest by induction? (Not sure if that kind of proof is plausible)

Comment: I just read that Nagura (1952) proved that for all $n$ bigger then 25, there exists a prime between $n$ and  $1.2 \times n$. Is this true? If so, then $p_{n} \leq 1.44p_{n-2}$ for all $n$ bigger then 25, so showing that the improved betranda postulate holds for primes less than 25, is sufficient to prove it right, right?

Comment: See the Wikipedia article   Bertrand's Postulate  , especially the section Better Results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a lot of improvements of the Bertrand postulate but yes, in this case it's sufficient to use that there is a prime between $n$ and $6n/5$, $n
 $ sufficiently large (as you write $n \geq 25$). So we have $$p_{n-2}<p_{n-1}<\frac{6p_{n-2}}{5}
 $$ and $$ p_{n-1}<p_{n}<\frac{6p_{n-1}}{5}=p_{n-1}+\frac{p_{n-1}}{5}
 $$ then $$p_{n}<\frac{36p_{n-2}}{25}\Rightarrow p_{n}-1<\frac{25p_{n}}{18}<2p_{n-2}.
 $$